# prestashop module not ready for php 7

Tags: php, prestashop, deprecated

I've a problem with module that is OK with PHP 5 but not with PHP 7...

I know thats is this line which is in cause:

`$this->$_GET ['load_function']($params);`

I put here a sample of the code:

```
 $params = array('method' => $_GET ['load_function'],'reload_after'=>Tools::getValue('reload_after'),'js_callback'=>Tools::getValue('js_callback'));    $this->_preLoadFunctionProcess($params);    $this->$_GET ['load_function']($params);
```

Is there someone which could help me to change this code and that will be OK with PHP7. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/migration70.incompatible.php) says these might work :

```
$this->{$_GET['load_function']}($params);
```

Comment: That's all... and everything work well ... Tanks a lot Matt... Great!!!